# How to do "burst reading" of mpu6050's sensor registers?

Tags: cpu-registers, mpu6050

In "MPU-6050 Register Map and Descriptions Revision 3.2"  it talks about burst reading data from registers mpu6050.

```
The data within the  accelerometer sensors’  internal register set  is always updated at the Sample 
Rate. Meanwhile, the user-facing read register set duplicates the  internal register set’s data values 
whenever the serial interface is idle. This guarantees that a **burst read** of sensor registers will read 
measurements from  the same sampling instant. Note that if burst reads are not used, the user is 
responsible for ensuring a set of single byte reads correspond to a single sampling instant by 
checking the Data Ready interrupt.
```

How to do  "burst reading" of mpu6050's sensor registers?